# Meteor observeChanges(). How to check the actual changes?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a code that looks like this

```
Trades.find().observeChanges({
    changed: function(id, fields) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Where each `Trades` has an array of items inside

```
TradesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    // ...
    items: {
        type: [String]
    },
    // ...
});

Trades.attachSchema(TradesSchema);
```

These items are being changed sometimes, and I want to track the changes. The code works fine, except that in `fields` it returns all the items, not only the items that were changed.

Is there any way to see which exactly item was changed without changing the structure of the collection?

Comment: It looks like this cannot be achieved sorely by `observeChanges` since its  `changed` always gives the new values. Try `observe` instead which gives you both the new and old documents for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Season for the hint!

---

`observeChanges` only gives the new values, so you have to use `observe`, since it returns both the new and old documents. Then you need to compare them to see what exactly got changed. ([See docs for `observe` on meteor.com)](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe)

```
Trades.find().observe({
    changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument) {
        // compare newDocument to oldDocument to find out what has changed
    }
});
```